# What does $(0:x)$ mean?

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation, homological-algebra

The following excerpt is from Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a view toward Algebraic Geometry" on pg. 424

> We can decide whether an element $x\in R$ is a nonzerodivisor from the homology of the complex $K(x): 0\to R\xrightarrow{x} R$, which is $(0:x)$.

What does $(0:x)$ mean? And what is $K(x):0\to R\xrightarrow{x} R$? I know that it is a short exact sequence. But I don't know what this is exactly.

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the map from $R$ to $R$ might be as simple as multiplication by $x$. Since $x$ is a nonzero divisor, you can easily show that this causes the map to be injective as specified.

Comment: That's correct Jake.

Comment: @Jake- But then what is $(0:x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $(0:x)$ is the set of elements $r$ of $R$, such that $rx=0$; called annihilator of $x$.

Note that

- In the complex $K(x): 0\to R\xrightarrow{x} R$, the homomorphism $\xrightarrow{x}$ is multiplication by $x$. So $ker (\xrightarrow{x}) = \{r\in R| rx=0\}=(0:x)$ (and this is the homology). The complex is *not* an exact sequence unless the homology is zero.
- "$x\in R$ is a nonzerodivisor" iff "there is no non-zero element $r$ of $R$, such that $rx=0$", which means:  $(0:x)=0.$